# JS/React How to prevent data from being fetched if URL doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, state

I'm writing an APP that fetches data from an API - based on user's actions.

I have a problem, because I have a search bar that changes the value of state. Then I use that state in the place of **${search}** in this link

`` var baseUrl = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=${search}&apikey=demo`; ``

using that link I then fetch data based on user's input which is stored in search/setSearch state..

However the app completely crashes quite often.. because the app starts to pull data from the API whenever state changes.. for example if user wants to check data for "MSFT" ( Microsoft company ), and starts typing M-S-F-T.. the app will crash as **it's trying to fetch data for every single letter that the user enters**

so it goes to:

```
`alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=M&apikey=demo`; // M

`alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MS&apikey=demo`; // MS

`alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSF&apikey=demo`; // MSF

`alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo`; // MSFT
```

and tries to fetch data for every letter entered in the search bar

If the link doesn't exist, the app will crash ( this is the ***PROBLEM!*** )

and give me an error saying! "Cannot convert undefined or null to object" - of couse.. the link doesnt exist so its undefined/null as there's nothing to get

Anyways, I need to find a way to handle the app in a way that at least it doesn't crash, and only fetches data if the link is correct.. I tried to use lodash.debounce ( something like setTimeout ) to wait a few seconds to allow the user to finish writing a full name of the stock.. however if the user erases the search, then the app tries to fetch data for an empty string

`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=&apikey=demo`;

(after symbol= it passes nothing, **there's no such link so the app crashes after failing to fetch proper data** )

I thought this could potentially be fixed with conditional rendering - and I tried to render the data conditionally (if chart == undefined then ... ).. but if the link is wrong - the app crashes as always, whether its rendered conditionally or not!

Just for reference, here's the component in which I'm rendering the search bar //

```
const StockSearchBar = () => {
  const { search, setSearch } = useContext(SearchContext); // state is stored in context API in another file


  function handleButtonEvents(e) {
        handleClick();
    setTimeout(() => window.location.reload(), 3000);
    }

  const handleSearch = (e) => { // searchbar functionality 
    e.preventDefault();
    setSearch(e.target.value.toUpperCase());
    debounce(() => setSearch(e.target.value.toUpperCase()), 2000); // debounce 2000 milliseconds
    // setTimeout(() => setSearch(e.target.value.toUpperCase()), 2500);
  };


  const handleClick = (e) => { // this is for backend - ignore it

    if (setSearch !== '') {

      const options = 
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type':  'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({search}),
      };
  
      const response = fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/search`, options);
      console.log("search entered");
      console.log(response)
    };
}


  
  return (
      
      <>
    <div className="searchBar">
      <label>Look for Stocks or Cryptos: </label>

// this is the searchbar
<input type='text' onChange={handleSearch} onKeyPress={(ev) => {
if (ev.key === "Enter") {
handleButtonEvents();
}}}
placeholder={search} required/>
      <Button variant="success" type="submit" onClick={handleButtonEvents}  >Search</Button>
    </div>
    <h1 className="src">{search}</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default StockSearchBar;
```

Basically, I need to figure out a way to prevent data from being fetched if the link (based on state) isn't a proper link. Or at least that's what I think my problem is.

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const SearchContext = createContext();

export function SearchProvider({ children }) {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("AAPL")
    return (
        <SearchContext.Provider value={{ search, setSearch }}>{children}</SearchContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default SearchContext;
```

^ This is my context api file - it's where state is stored and shared across the app

One solution I think could possibly help is switching onChange with onSubmit or onClick and then saving state to localStorage ( because onClick/onSubmit refreshes the whole page including state.. I tried e.preventDefault but for some reason it refuses to work in the browser giving me an error that "preventDefault(); is not a function"...) however, I'm still trying to figure out how to do it.. but logically it makes sense

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo  --> demo link to the API for public use

**EDIT // UPDATE**
ok, so I got the app to work a lot better with an if (searchbar is empty then dont set state) - thanks to Robert's comment..

```
  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target.value !== ``) {
    setSearch(e.target.value.toUpperCase())
    }
  };
```

I have not added this file (component), however I think it's important to include it for obvious reasons as the error is coming from here

```
function LineChart(props) {
  const { search, setSearch } = useContext(SearchContext);

  var baseUrl = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=${search}&apikey=demo`;

  const [chart, setChart] = useState();

  useEffect(() => { // fetching data from api
      axios.get(baseUrl)
      .then(res => {

        setChart(res.data);

      })
  }, [baseUrl]);

   useEffect(()=>{}, [chart]);

     const stockPrices = useMemo(() => chart && Object.values(chart['Time Series (Daily)']).map(i => i['1. open']).reverse(), [chart]); // store stock prices in stockPrices 

     const stockDates = useMemo(() => chart && Object.keys(chart['Time Series (Daily)']).map(x => x.replace(/\d{4}-/, "")).reverse(), [chart]); // store dates in stockDates



// display stock chart + settings using chart.js
  var data = {
    labels: stockDates,
    datasets: [{
      label: `${search}`,
      data: stockPrices,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,116,89,0.05)",
      borderColor: "rgba(255,105,75,1)",
      borderWidth: 2,
      pointBorderColor: "#2984c5",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'black',
      fill: true,
      pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(41, 132, 197, 1)",
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 7,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointHitRadius: 30,
      tension: 0.3,
    }]
  };



  var options = {
    plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: '',
      labels: {
        color: 'white',
        font: {
          size: 30,
          family: 'verdana',
        },
      }
    }
  },
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    responsive: false,
    radius: 3,
    scales: {
      y: {
        ticks: {
          callback: function (value) {
            return "$" + value;
          },
          color: 'rgba(210,230,244,1)',
          font: {
            size: 12,
            family: "Verdana" // Add your font here to change the font of your legend label
          }
        },
        grid: {
          color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.02)',
        }
      },
      x: {
        grid: {
          color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.02)',
        },
        ticks: {
          color: 'rgba(210,230,244,1)',
          font: {
            family: "Verdana" // Add your font here to change the font of your legend label
          }

        }
      },
    },

    
  }

  return (

    <>
      <div className='chartcont'>
      
          <Line data={data} height={800} width={1200} options={options} /> {/* DISPLAY CHART BASED ON THE FETCHED DATA */}

        </div>

      <button onClick={() => setSearch("NIO")}>CLICK ME</button>
      <h1 className='src'>{search}</h1> {/* ADDED THIS FOR TESTING PURPOSES */}

    </>
    );
  }
export default LineChart;
```

Comment: Only fetch when the search is not empty and check the response to see if it's "ok"  , i.e 200, to either output good data or a generic, "no results found for your query"

Comment: hey @RobertRocha  I added this..  so far my app is crashing a lot less ! thanks a lot - I'm gonna have to tinker thru this a bit more unfortunately, but thanks again it really does mean a lot

const handleSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target.value !== ``) {
    setSearch(e.target.value.toUpperCase())
    }
  };

Comment: could you give me some more guidance on how to handle the get request with axios? i will update the file that's causing the app to crash.. i didnt post it

Comment: https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of error that might defeat a fetch request, either the link doesn't exist, or a link exists but doesn't have data to be read. A error-catch block can be used to log the error without crashing the programme. I have used the following structure to fetch from a few thousand generated links where every now and then, one of the links is bad or the json data not present. It prevented crashes and reported silently to console.

```
fetch(`${url}`)
  .then(response => {
     if (!response.ok){throw new Error ('Bad Response');} 
     else { return response.json()};
  })
  .then(data => { 
      // process data here or pass to processing function;    
      parseData(data)
  })
  .catch(error => {
     // if in a loop can also log which url failed;
     console.log('error made: ', error);
  });
```